# Blocked by Play Protect while installing APK

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, android-keystore

I am in the process of testing out a hybrid Cordova/Android app on a handful of real Android devices.  I have done the following

- Created a keystore using keytool and added a certificate to it as follows `keytool -genkey -alias DOMAIN -keyalg RSA -validity 10000 -keystore keystore.ks`.  While doing so I have provided answers to all entries such as Name, Organization Unit etc and not left anything at Unknown
- I place the resulting keystore.ks file in my Cordova project in the `platforms\android` folder instruct Gradle to use it by creating a `debug-signing.properties` file with the following contents

  storeFile=keystore.ks
  keyAlias=[ALIAS]
  storePassword=[STORE_PWD]
  keyPassword=[KEY_PWD]

With this in place I issue `cordova clean && cordova prepare && cordova build android` which promptly produces the APK.  However, when I try to open and install the APK on my test devices I get the message

**Blocked by Play Protect**

> Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer.  Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.

I am clearly missing something out here.  I'd be grateful to anyone who can tell me what that might be.

Comment: You can try to build a debug APK, I know on  android studio its a simple button click, But cordova I am Unsure, But a debug APK will avoid play protect

Comment: I am building a debug apk.  For good meausre I did this again with `cordova build android --debug` - although that is the default anyway - but still the same result.

Comment: Did you try to enable the "Allow install from unknown sources" option on your devices?

Comment: Of course - unknown sources is allowed or else the APK would not even get opened by Android to attempt installation.  The message I mention above happens **during** the installation process.

Comment: I Fixed this once by creating a new keystore